# Logo for Self Published

Tags: self-publishing, symbolism

Is there any logo for self published books? Since I am not approaching any publishing company, it would be nice if there is a self-publish logo that can be used at front cover of my book in place of a publishing company logo.
Since there is some new logo such as Copyleft, Creative commons etc, I am assuming "self published" might have a standardized or universally accepted logo.

Comment: Why would there be?  What organisation would oversee it?

Comment: @Chenmunka It make the book look nice. Creative commons may oversee it

Comment: Why would Creative Commons oversee works that aren't published under Creative Commons but are self-published?  Your suggestion makes no sense.

Comment: Much better to design a logo that defines you or as your publishing imprint, and use it for multiple works to preserve uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is whether there is an industry-standard or commonly-recognized icon that marks a published work as "self-published."

No, there is not.

However, there are various self-publishing or indie-publishing organizations that you can join. Then you could add their logo to your publication page inside your book, and to the end of your online book description, saying something like "Member in good standing of __".

I love the IBPA ([Independent Book Publishers Association](https://www.ibpa-online.org/page/ListofBenefits)). That includes indie authors (who act as their own publishers) and "indie publishers" which are small publishers or small presses that are not affiliated with any of the giant publishing conglomerates that dominate the publishing world. Since you're asking this question, you could benefit a great deal from joining them and reading their articles for newbies to the publishing world— it's all good stuff.

"ALLi" is great too ([Alliance of Independent Authors](https://www.allianceindependentauthors.org/member-benefits/) ...not sure why their acronym is weird like that). It's similar to the IBPA but laser-focused on you, the self-publishing author. And honestly a friendlier organization than the IBPA, which is full of friendly people but organizational culture is more "corporate"-feeling.

Choose one, join it, and you're welcome to brag about your professional affiliation wherever you might otherwise reveal info about your publisher.

I hope this helps!